# How do you calculate the range of trigonometric function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

What is the range of following function $f(x) = 3|\sin x|$?

I tried multiplying by $3$ with the range of $\sin x$ function which is $[-1, 1]$ which gave me the outcome $[-3, 3]$, but I feel like it's not the correct range of it. How to get the range of it?

Comment: You're close. You are right that $\sin(x) \in [-1, 1]$. However, what happens the negative half of that range when you take the absolute value?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but it's $|\sin x|$ that is scaled by a factor of $3$. The absolute value guarantees that the values are non-negative:
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcl}
-1 & \leq & \sin x \phantom{|} & \leq & 1 \\
\implies \qquad 0 & \leq & |\sin x| & \leq & 1 \\
\implies \qquad 0 & \leq & 3\,|\sin x| & \leq & 3
\end{array}
$$

If we're being really careful, we should note that on each line, these numbers are bounds on possible values for the function in the middle. So, these inequalities show that the range of $f(x)$ is a subset of the interval $[0, 3]$.

But why is it *all* of that interval, with no gaps? In other words, why is it the case that for any real number $y$ such that $0 \leq y \leq 3$, we can find an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$? Such an $x$ would have to satisfy $3|\sin x| = y$, so $|\sin x| = \tfrac13 y$ or
$$
\sin x = \tfrac13 y, 
$$
where $\sin x \geq 0$. Remember that $0 \leq y \leq 3$, so $0 \leq \tfrac13 y \leq 1$. And we can always find an $x$ (representing an angle in the first quadrant actually) such that $\sin x$ gives that number in $[0, 1]$, so we're good.

Here's [an interactive graphic](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o7wmylxcty), where you can grab the black dot on the $y$-axis and drag it up and down (or type in a particular value of $y$) and see that it's in the range of $f$.

[image: Absolute value trig function.]